# Theme Twenty Seventeen - Make Margins Smaller So That Text is Wider

Tags: text, theme-twenty-seventeen

I'm sure this is a very common question so I apologize in advance if this annoys some people.

This is my first ever blog so I have little to absolutely no knowledge on how to manipulate the elements to my liking.

The text in the blog uses about a third of the actual sites size and leaves a lot of empty space.

I would like this to use about 75% of the websites size. Attached is a image to give an idea of what is currently going on.

If you are going to tell me to use any form of coding, could you please include how I go about inserting said code into the website as again, super new here.

Thank you so much for anyone that is available to help.[image]

Comment: Not sure I can provide you with the answer you want, but what you'll need to do is add your custom CSS to the 'Additional CSS'  panel in the customizer (see the bottom of your screen capture on the left)... ...You'll need to use your browsers developer tools to identify the container, find the CSS/style rules that set the placement and width and paste them here, then someone can assist you in changing it.
Side note, there is research that indicates that making text rows too wide makes them less legible and engaging.  The default WP themes use a lot of internet research to make these decisions

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot, at the bottom of the left menu, there is 'Additional CSS', add this code there. Then hit publish.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 48em){
 body.page-two-column:not(.archive) #primary .entry-content {
    width: 75%;
}
}
```